# Mock spring MessageContext

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

i would like to mock these methods:

```
SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();
SoapBody requestBody = saajSoapMessage.getSoapBody();
```

I tried it with this

```
messageContextMock = mock(MessageContext.class);
saajSoapMessageMock = mock(SaajSoapMessage.class);

when(messageContextMock.getRequest()).thenReturn((SaajSoapMessage) saajSoapMessageMock);
when(saajSoapMessageMock.getSoapBody()).thenReturn(soapBodyMock);
```

But I have problem with mocking `getSoapBody()` because Junit wrote me:

```
at org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.getSoapBody(AbstractSoapMessage.java:36)
```

How to mock this operation correctly?

EDIT (full stack):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.getSoapBody(AbstractSoapMessage.java:36)
    at com.project.my.WebMessageTest.setUp(WebMessageTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Can you put the full stack trace rather than the one line please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a body to your mocked objects, try this:

```
messageContextMock = mock(MessageContext.class);

saajSoapMessageMock = mock(SaajSoapMessage.class);
soapEnvelopeMock = mock(SOAPEnvelope.class);

when(saajSoapMessageMock.getEnvelope()).thenReturn(soapEnvelopeMock);
when(messageContextMock.getRequest()).thenReturn(saajSoapMessageMock);
```

Comment: Still the same. I used:

    `messageContextMock = mock(MessageContext.class);
    saajSoapMessageMock = mock(SaajSoapMessage.class);
    soapMessageMock = mock(SOAPMessage.class);
    soapBodyMock = mock(SOAPBody.class);
    when(soapMessageMock.getSOAPBody()).thenReturn(soapBodyMock);
when(saajSoapMessageMock.getSaajMessage()).thenReturn(soapMessageMock);
       when(messageContextMock.getRequest()).thenReturn(saajSoapMessageMock);
        when(soapMessageMock.getSOAPBody()).thenReturn(soapBodyMock);`

Comment: There was an error in my answer, I was mocking the return for getSoapBody() on two different mocks, one of which was wrong. I don't know if this will affect your results but may be worth a try. Getting a null pointer like you are shows something isn't mocked correctly. Debug through your test code and look at the mock objects created. Look at the path of SaajSoapMessage -> SOAPMessage -> SOAPBody, are any of these null?

Comment: So, nullpointer is in this code:

`    /** Returns <code>getEnvelope().getBody()</code>. */
    public final SoapBody getSoapBody() {
        return getEnvelope().getBody();
    }`

null is envelope, implementatnion, messageFactory, saajMessage

Comment: I've added some more mocks to the answer, this time it should mock the SOAPEnvelope, and the SOAPPart class that is used to get the envelope from the SOAPMessage.

Comment: Unfortunatelly same.

But for your info saajSoapMessageMock has only getSaajMessage method not getSoapMessage method.

Comment: Ah, try adding -----  when(saajSoapMessageMock.getEnvelope() ).thenReturn(soapEnvelopeMock); (answer updated with this attempt ;))

Comment: Good, It was in `saajSoapMessageMock.getEnvelope()` :-)

All working example is:
`        saajSoapMessageMock = mock(SaajSoapMessage.class);
        soapEnvelopeMock = mock(SoapEnvelope.class);


        when(messageContextMock.getRequest()).thenReturn(saajSoapMessageMock);
        when(saajSoapMessageMock.getEnvelope()).thenReturn(soapEnvelopeMock);`

Comment: Glad you got it working, updated the answer for future searching sake. Do you want to accept it so the working solution is obvious out of all this :)